# How to append JSON object to JSON object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

so i have this JSON file:

```
{"fjord-200-200.jpg":[]}
```

I read it using

```
let data = fs.readFileSync(cachedName);
let cachedInJSON: JSON = JSON.parse(data.toString());
```

so i have now JSON object, that i want to append to this new JSON object

```
let newData = {
        fileNameFormatted: []
    }
```

when i tried using

```
let newJson = {...cachedInJSON, ...newData}
```

Result was this:

```
{"fjord-200-200.jpg":[],"fileNameFormatted":[]}
```

**Wanted result that i want to achieve is:**

```
{"fjord-200-200.jpg":[],"fjord-300-300.jpg":[]}
```

fileNameFormatted is a variable holding `fjord-300-300.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let newData = {
        [fileNameFormatted]: [] // Notice the brackets around the key
    }
```